# Swift: Lock button position because it is being moved by UITextview? Problems with constraints?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am on a deadline and have spent over 5 hours trying to get this to work - I am having a problem with a UITextview and a moving button. I have not found 1 answer or post that has had this same issue.

I have a unbutton and a uitextview placed on a xib. These are "locked" in position on all devices via the Add Missing Constraints button. At first, I had the Unbutton placed over the textfield (they are the same size).

I have a function that moves the UIButton up (to be above the uitextview) or down (back over the textview) depending on if it has already been pressed:

```
 @IBAction func enterText(sender: UIButton) {
        print("time to enter text")

        if !textOpen
        {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
            self.textBtn.center.y -= self.textBtn.bounds.height
        })


        }
        else {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
                self.textBtn.center.y += self.textBtn.bounds.height
            })

        }

        textOpen = !textOpen
    }
```

This is the ONLY PIECE OF CODE that moves the Uibutton. ONLY piece. 
I am trying to achieve this affect - when button pressed, moves up to reveal textview so user can edit text. Pressed again, button moves back over textview. Like this:

[image]

But I am having a very large problem. After the button moves up, if the user goes to enter in the textview, the button snaps back to position. Or sometimes just moves sporadically. The textview is NOT calling the `enterText` method as nothing is printed. I don't know how it has the power to move the button.

I tried placing the button up initially and for the most part then the textview caused the button to move back to THIS position (not over it), so I think the textview sends the button back its original position as indicated by the auto layout constraints that are set. I don't understand how this works.

I have tried everything - trying to lock the button and textview together, resizing the textview, programmatically creating a button to avoid dealing with the constraints. Nothing is working and I need to have this done soon. Running out of ideas.

The button ONLY snaps back when the textview is enabled - if the user is unable to type nothing is affected. So my last straw -

is there a way to LOCK the position of a button on the screen while the textview is being edited? I know there is a method that detects if text is being entered and have tried manually setting the center x and y of the UIButton but again, I think the constraints have overruled this.

Is there another way to configure the constraints to make this work? Or is this effect impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you need to move the "Tell Us What Happened" button. This is what you can do :

1) Set up a bottom constraint for this button with the top of the "Take a photo" button. Initially, its constant will be 0.

2) Now have an outlet for this constraint(suppose I name it **bottomConst**) and do this :

```
 @IBAction func enterText(sender: UIButton) {
            print("time to enter text")

            if !textOpen
            {
             self.bottomConst.constant = 30 //whatever height your textview has

             self.textBtn.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()

            }
            else {

             self.bottomConst.constant = 0 

             self.textBtn.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()

            }
           UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
               self.textBtn.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: nil)

            textOpen = !textOpen
        }
```

I hope this helps you.